# Is there any reason why I should use parentheses when calling new in PHP?

Tags: php, coding-style

When there are no arguments, we have these two options:

```
$obj = new MyClass;
```

vs.

```
$obj = new MyClass();
```

I always pick the former, just because.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Duplicate from stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830401/php-parentheses-when-creating-new-object

Comment: And also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873111/instantiate-a-class-with-or-without-parentheses

Comment: You can't duplicate questions cross-network. Specific, answerable questions about coding standards/conventions are on-topic here.

Comment: However, given the existence of the question on Stack Overflow you have to wonder why felt the need to ask it here.

Comment: @ChrisF Oh I'm sorry. Next time I'll just read the entire internet to avoid bothering you with my "duplicate".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Include them. It isn't much extra work and it won't confuse people that don't know that leaving them off the parenthesis is an option.

Comment: +1 I didn't know you could leave them off. It would have confused me!

Answer (score 3):

Include them; with PHP, you want to be as specific and unambiguous as you can.

Comment: In **ANY** programming,  you want to be as specific and unambiguous as you can.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Though this isn't really ambiguous, just confusing for people who don't know about this optional syntax.

Comment: Yes, it's not really possible for one to be ambiguous in a programming language, as far as the computer is concerned, because it still knows what to do. Rather I meant that dropping little bits of unnecessary syntax here and there is a slippery slop of special cases that results in code that simply takes longer for other humans, or your future self, to understand.